# Can I store a page with the NOINDEX metatag?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, meta-tags, noindex

I'm doing a webcreawler and now I'm trying to follow the robots.txt and the metatags `NOINDEX` and `NOFOLLOW`.

`NOFOLLOW` says me to not follow the links in the page, but and the `NOINDEX`?
I understand that it's to not index the page on the searches, but I won't do any search, only store the page in the database.

I will disrespect the `NOINDEX` tag if I store in the database or this only applies to searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No particular reason not to store it. As long as you're not indexing it and returning it in a search result. You're not disrespecting the meaning of `NOINDEX` unless you return it as a search result.